# Software that is functionally similar to Deep Freeze for MacOS 10.13

Tags: macos, high-sierra, apfs

Faronics, the developers of Deep Freeze have stated that they have no intention of supporting APFS, and by extension 10.13.

I know the Apple Stores used to use Deep Freeze and are now using a utility that is functionally similar to Deep Freeze on 10.13 on APFS, but definitely isn't Deep Freeze.

Does anyone know what this utility is, or any alternatives to Deep Freeze that supports APFS and MacOS 10.13?

This will be used in an enterprise environment, so something with proper support and licensing would be idea.

Thanks,

Nabeel

Edit: Yes, this is a recommendation request post, however there is no other way to reword this post, and Faronics basically built this industry, so it's a little tone deaf to not mention them in the post.

Comment: I used the "Alternative To" website and it listed Smart Shield as a cross-platform alternative to Deep Freeze, You can check it out here: http://centuriontech.com

Comment: @nabeeir - As a software rec question, this fits the bill for me. It's clear, concise & has a distinct purpose, as the well-known player is out of the game. It's not 'kan I haz a mp3 soft' ;)

Comment: @jmh Smart Shield does not support anything past 10.9

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. The people over at the SuperUser forum keep giving me grief regarding this question and seem to refuse to answer it. They just seem to ask questions like "What's that?" instead of googling it or realizing that they might not be the person to answer the question since they don't know what I'm asking. It's been very frustrating.

Comment: SU does tend to jump on any software/hardware rec question, even though their own meta clearly states that software recs are fine if they fit certain criteria. I wouldn't let it upset you, we're nicer here anyway ;-))

Answer (score 1):

In terms of restore-on-reboot solutions it really boils down to Deep Freeze and Reboot Restore Rx. The latter of which doesn't support Mac's currently but will in the future from what I've hear.

What the Apple Store uses is akin to loading a disk image automatically. It's a bit more cumbersome than Deep Freeze or other similar solutions but at the very least it's compatible with APFS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, less than 2 months after this question was asked, Faronics released a version of Deep Freeze that is APFS compatible, with express support for 10.13 and 10.14 now.

(As such, I suspect that “[Faronics] have stated that they have no intention of supporting APFS, and by extension 10.13.” must have been a radical misunderstanding, probably of a “We have nothing to announce at the moment.” kind of statement.)

Comment: I called Faronics and talked to them. This is what they told me at the time. I don't know if the representative I talked to was ill-informed, or chose to not tell me the truth of their intentions, but this is what I was told by them directly.